# Provisioning a team with hundreds of guest users

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I was wondering how would I go about provisioning a team that will have hundreds of guest users?

I looked at PowerShell and School Data Sync, but it's only possible to add members within the organization. Is there a way to add about 13.000 guests (in an organisation that has 250 employees), without having to add them individually?
It's an EDU tenant.

We would split 13.000 users to multiple teams, so 10k limit will not be reached per team.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: **Thank You** for accepting answer, this will help others in the community with similar question. Could you please spare one min to let us know how we did by clicking on **[this feedback link](https://aka.ms/DevSupportFeedback)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are two ways to do this. One which you already mentioned - PowerShell - You can add people outside your organization(Guests). Adding guests is a two step process. 1st you need to invite user, 2nd add him to the team. Check this documentation for how to [add the guest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-quickstart-invite-powershell) and how to [add bulk users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/tutorial-bulk-invite) using PowerShell script.
And second option is to use [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: I updated the information from my post. It's 13.000 guest users in an organisation that has 250 employees. Is it still possible?

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT problem is not about ways of creation. Its about license and guest user limitations for MS-teams.

Comment: @pangi, As long as count is less then 10k, it should not have any issue. Check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/limits-specifications-teams)

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, you have to add guest users in azure active directory. If you need some special features like MFA then for guest users you can add up to 5 guest users for 1 license otherwise there are no restrictions. In the past I created 132 guest users for my azure account.

Comment: Note: My answer is for organization's licensed account. About other accounts, I am not sure.

Comment: Hi, I just got some additional information. It's going to be 13.000 guests in an organisation that has 250 employees. That means that the 5:1 ratio is off. Is there a workaround?

Comment: check this link for other limitations on teams https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/limits-specifications-teams . Even if you add that many users there is no point because of other limitations. As it is license based I don't think about any workaround. If MS-Teams allow unlimited number of guests then no one will buy license from them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to add guest users in your Teams organization.

1. Add guest users as mail contacts in your exchange organization
2. Add the contacts in to Teams
   You can find a short video tutorial prepared in my blog explaining this in the link shown below:
   If you are looking for the solution which I explain in my blog, I can help out further in preparing PowerShell script to add all users by PowerShell cmdlet

[Add External Contacts in Microsoft Teams](http://cloudcompute.info/add-external-contacts-in-microsoft-teams/)

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: I updated the information from my post. It's 13.000 guest users in an organisation that has 250 employees. Is it still possible?

Comment: Hello, Understand Licensing - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/guest-access#:~:text=Teams%20doesn't%20restrict%20the,5%20guests%20per%20licensed%20user

There are ways to add bulk members to Exchange online contacts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/bulk-import-external-contacts?view=o365-worldwide). 
Now, you can't bulk add Teams guests in PowerShell. Solution is here:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/micrsoft-teams-add-bulk-of-team-members-from-csv/d463b033-00a7-4334-9ff3-7edace17e3dd
Thanks, Manu